# Can't figure out if its just bad code or if its the IDE but it doesn't even work on replit

Tags: python, ascii-art

All im trying to do is get the program to call on a .mp4 file and parse through each frame before translating the frames into ascii art and then repeating the output in the terminal until some key is pressed, spent a month trying to get it to work on my own and after a week of trying to get chatgpt or copilot to fix the bugs I'm all out of ideas. its possible its my system but I've tried the global python on my system, I've tried anaconda and andaconda ran through vs code. it might just be bad code I'm all self taught so...yeah here's the code

```
import cv2
from ascii_graph import Pyasciigraph

def convert_frame_to_ascii(frame):
    height, width = frame.shape[:2]
    aspect_ratio = width / height
    new_width = 120
    new_height = int(new_width / aspect_ratio / 2)
    resized_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (new_width, new_height))
    ascii_frame = ''
    ascii_graph = Pyasciigraph()

    for row in resized_frame:
        for pixel in row:
            ascii_frame += ascii_graph.graph([pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2]])[0][0]
        ascii_frame += '\n'

    return ascii_frame

def play_video(file_path):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if not ret:
            break

        ascii_frame = convert_frame_to_ascii(frame)
        print(ascii_frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_file = 'path/to/video.mp4'
    play_video(video_file)
```

and the traceback looks like this or some variation of this

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/runner/vidtoascii/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/home/runner/vidtoascii/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 111, in bootstrap
    load_first_config(['config.py'], True)
  File "/home/runner/vidtoascii/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 109, in load_first_config
    raise ImportError('OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: {}. Check OpenCV installation.'.format(fnames))
ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.
```

I tried swapping different modules and libraries and packages as well as changing interpreters and IDEs, I've tried running it on the cloud, for some reason the issue is getting whatever environment I'm using to download and import the prerequisites.

edit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/runner/vidtoascii/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/home/runner/vidtoascii/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 111, in bootstrap
    load_first_config(['config.py'], True)
  File "/home/runner/vidtoascii/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 109, in load_first_config
    raise ImportError('OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: {}. Check OpenCV installation.'.format(fnames))
ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.
```

Comment: You haven't told us what actually happens.

Comment: And you may be a bit confused.  `ascii_graph` does not produce ASCII art.  It produces histograms.  https://pypi.org/project/ascii_graph/  You might look at https://levelup.gitconnected.com/python-ascii-art-generator-60ba9eb559d7 .

Comment: @TimRoberts ill get a traceback or error on the line that first uses open cv or ascii graph. and yeah I've thought about using pillow or PIL whatever works now but I get the same issue.

Comment: "get a traceback or error" doesn't help us at all.  WHICH error?  WHAT traceback?  To get good help, you must provide enough details for us to diagnose things.

Comment: this isn't all of it only cause there's a character limit
Traceback (most recent call last):
    import cv2
  File "/home/runner/vidtoascii/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/home/runner/vidtoascii/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 111, in bootstrap
   raise ImportError('OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: {}. Check OpenCV installation.'.format(fnames))
ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76266095/edit) your question and include your traceback.

Comment: "missing configuration file" is pretty explicit, and should be a very strong hint about what you need to do to fix it. :)

Comment: How, EXACTLY, did you install openCV?

Comment: @TimRoberts when I first got the idea I did it using pip because that's how every link on google said, but when I was trying to do it with an environment through anaconda I literally sat and sifted through every single library and module and package to look for cv2 thinking it was different from open-cv. again im sorry im trying to teach myself too much too fast probably, Ive always been good with computers but up until less than a year ago my only experience coding was writing bash files to constantly restart my teachers computer or open the terminal a million times so we wouldnt do work lol.

Comment: So, did you copy a bunch of files by hand, then?  `config.py` should be the main directory of the cv2 package, such as `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cv2`.  If it's not there, then you could try `pip install --upgrade --force opencv-python`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that works, based on the link I included in the comments above.

```
import cv2
ASCII_CHARS = ["@", "#", "$", "%", "?", "*", "+", ";", ":", ",", "."]

def resize(image, new_width = 100):
    height, width = image.shape[:2]
    new_height = new_width * height // width
    return cv2.resize(image, (new_width, new_height))

def to_grayscale(image):
    return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

def pixel_to_ascii(image):
    aimage = []
    for row in image:
        aimage.append( ''.join(ASCII_CHARS[col//25] for col in row) )
    return '\n'.join(aimage)

def play_video(file_path):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if not ret:
            break

        frame = resize(frame)
        frame = to_grayscale(frame)
        ascii = pixel_to_ascii(frame)
        print(ascii)
        print('\n')

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_file = '/home/timr/Music/Scores/PuttinOnTheRitz.mp4'
    play_video(video_file)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look for that article and commenting fixed code but I get the same errors, will edit question again to add it.